# Pass secrets to environment variable in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-secrets

I want to pass value(s) from docker secrets to environment variables.
Given that I have local filename `password.txt` with a single line in that, which is a password, I do the following according to https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/

```
version: '3.9'
services:
    foo:
        build: .
        restart: "no"
        privileged: true
        env_file: env_file
        environment:
            FOO_PASS: /run/secrets/foo_pass
        image: foo:latest
        secrets:
            - foo_pass
secrets:
    foo_pass:
        file: ~/foo_pass.txt
```

And I'd expect that environment variable `FOO_PASS` to be equal to what is in the file. Instead it's equal to `/run/secrets/foo_pass`. What is wrong?

Also is the an option to pass multiple variable values from single secret file?

Comment: you can pass environment file path using `env-file:` [ref](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)

Comment: "And I'd expect that environment variable FOO_PASS to be equal to what is in the file." Why would you expect that? The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#environment) is pretty clear: `environment` section is for setting the value of environment variables to string values.

Comment: the link to documentation is even more confusing where it show SESSION_SECRET in example

Comment: Using env-file makes little sense when docker inspect can show you those credentials.